# SQL Query within Query (PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, t-sql

So I've got myself some php below that is intended to find the columns of the spikes table and build an html table accordingly with the results of the spikes query.

Naturally, I don't want to be running a query for each loop, so I defined $schema to query it before the loops. However, if i don't declare it within the while($spike...) section, it just doesn't work. What am I doing wrong here?

And please do not give me a proprietary response. I'm trying to stick to writing code as cross-compatible between sql solutions as possible.

```
// Queries
$q_spikes = "SELECT * FROM spikes";
$q_schema = "SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'spikes'";


// Table
echo "<table>";

    echo "<tr>";
    $schema = $conn->query($q_schema);

    while($info = $schema->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<td>" . $info['COLUMN_NAME'] . "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";

    $spikes = $conn->query($q_spikes);

    while($spike = $spikes->fetch_assoc()) {

        echo "<tr>";

        $schema = $conn->query($q_schema);

        while($info = $schema->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "<td>" . $spike[$info['COLUMN_NAME']] . "</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";

    }

echo "</table>";
```

Comment: I think a simple `array_keys($spike)` on the first row of the real query would do this with a lot less fuss and fiddle

Comment: Unless you need to prepare a statement with the values of the result of `$spikes` there's no real need to even do a query inside the loop, you can just query it before and use the value on every iteration.

Comment: Get rid of everything `$q_schema` and just iterate over `$spike`. Also what is the `N` prior to your string?

Answer (score 0):

Based on RiggsFolly's comment, I was able to achieve my goal with this:

```
    // Queries
    $q_spikes = "SELECT * FROM spikes";
    $needshead = true;

    // Table
    echo "<table>";
        $spikes = $conn->query($q_spikes);
        while($spike = $spikes->fetch_assoc()) {
            if($needshead) { 
                $needshead = false;
                echo '<tr>';
                    foreach ($spike as $key => $value) {
                    echo '<td>' . $key . '</td>';   
                    }
                echo '<tr>';
            }
            echo "<tr>";
                foreach ($spike as $key => $value) {
                    echo "<td>" . $value . '</td>'; 
                }
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    echo "</table>";
```